# CodenameOne - Dropdown List Design (FAQ Style)

Tags: codenameone

[image: FAQ Sample Screen]

Hi,

I am trying to achieve a similar screen to the one attached here using codename one. Its such that when a question is clicked, the answer drops down beneath it. The text would also have proper line breaks as it fills the screen width.

Is there any component I can use in achieving this using codename one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the `Tree` component and setting the icons to null explicitly. This should work reasonably well for something like that and include the animation etc.

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing that already. The transition works fine but then the contents dont break into new lines, instead it doesnt display the full text. Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: Thanks Shai, that worked :) ... Is there a way I can have a different style for the title while I have a different style for the child nodes like it is on the screenshot?

Comment: Sure, derive tree and override the create component method